# Handle command for remote pc

Tags: windows, cmd, remote-access, sysinternals

I want to run handle for a specific folder for a remote pc at my network so to know which processes are locking the folders.

tried:

```
handle /accepteula \\remotePcName\c:\myFolder

handle /accepteula \\remotePcName\User(name of the account)\c:\myFolder
```

and some other combinations with no luck getting

*No matching handles found.*

Is it possible to do this? Run handle for a remote pc?

Comment: is your c: shared out as `c:`? Is that what shows up when you browse to `\\remotePcName`? c: would not be a valid path name anyways due to the `:`. Perhaps you want `\\remotePcName\c$`

Comment: Actually I have it shared as C. Tried \\remotePcName\c but still getting No matching handles found

Comment: and from reading the handle docs, I doubt it can actually work on a UNC path anyways. The sort of information it needs isn't available remotely.

Comment: So no way to make it work? How about with an IP? Do you have a link for the doc?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Comment: you could try psexec to execute a remote copy of handle that's already on that machine. but that's opening a whole diferent ball of wax.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

I already have installed handle to the other machines so I think if it's possible to do by executing the handle at the remote machine it's ok for me.

Comment: Ok, by executing the handle with psexec I could take the results I want.

Here what I've done:

    psexec /accepteula \\remotePcName handle \myFolder

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try like this:

```
c:\powershell\Tools\psexec.exe \\remotePcName C:\handle.exe c:\myFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using invoke-command to execute 'handles' remotely?

```
$serverName = 'serverName'
$pathtoCheck = 'C:\temp' # folder you want to check on the remote server.
$pathtoHandle = 'c:\temp\handle.exe' #location of handle.exe on the remote server.

Invoke-command -ComputerName $serverName -Scriptblock {
    param(
    [string]$handles,
    [string]$pathToCheck
    )
     "$handles /accepteula $pathToCheck" | Invoke-Expression 
    } -ArgumentList $pathtoHandle,$pathtoCheck
```